# How to concatenate a string from path to directory and a multiple zip files names in a directory?

Tags: java, string

I am working on some script to atomize a manual function that I need to do almost daily.

My first problem is to build a String from Path and zip file name.
The second problem is to loop trough the zip file names (path+zip file name).

This is the path to directory with multiple zip files: `/Users/John.Smith/Desktop/Test_script/`

Here is a name of one of the many zip Files: `CRM_CI_20161016_000001_50661561.zip`

At the end I need to loop through the directory and sub-string from each zip file name the number `50661561` in order to manipulate it.

Can someone give me a suggestion for it?

This is my code give below to manipulate just one zip file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;



public class UnzipUtilityTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {



  // unzip file 

        String zipFilePath = "/Users/John.Smith/Desktop/Test_script/CRM_CI_20161016_000001_50661561.zip";
        String destDirectory = "/Users/John.Smith/Desktop/Test_script/test";
        UnzipUtility unzipper = new UnzipUtility();


        try {
            unzipper.unzip(zipFilePath, destDirectory);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            System.out.println("ERROR:Unzip did not work");
        }


 // read provider id       
        String old_prov_id = zipFilePath.substring(66, 74);
        System.out.println("Old provider ID :"+old_prov_id );

 // add +1 to provider ID
        int new_provider_ID = Integer.parseInt(old_prov_id);
        new_provider_ID++;
        System.out.println("New provider ID :"+new_provider_ID );


 // convert provider-id INT into String   

      String str_provider_id = Integer.toString(new_provider_ID);  
      System.out.println("New String provider ID :"+str_provider_id );  

 // concatenate two String into one
        StringBuilder bufferPDF = new StringBuilder()
                .append(new_provider_ID).append(".pdf");
            System.out.println(bufferPDF.toString()); 

            StringBuilder bufferXML = new StringBuilder()
                    .append(new_provider_ID).append(".xml");
                System.out.println(bufferXML.toString()); 

  // convert names of XML and PDF      

       Path sourcePDF = Paths.get("/Users/John.Smith/Desktop/Test_script/test/50661561.pdf");
        try {
            Files.move(sourcePDF, sourcePDF.resolveSibling(bufferPDF.toString()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Path sourceXML = Paths.get("/Users/John.Smith/Desktop/Test_script/test/50661561.xml");
        try {
            Files.move(sourceXML, sourceXML.resolveSibling(bufferXML.toString()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    // change provider-id and filename in xml file    

           try {

                String filepath = "/Users/John.Smith/Desktop/Test_script/test/50661562.xml";

                DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);

                // Get the root element provider-id 
                Node provider = doc.getElementsByTagName("provider-id").item(0);
                provider.setTextContent(str_provider_id);

                // Get the root element filename
                Node filename = doc.getElementsByTagName("filename").item(0);
                filename.setTextContent(str_provider_id);


                // write the content into xml file
                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
                transformer.transform(source, result);

                System.out.println("Done");

               } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
                pce.printStackTrace();
               } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
                tfe.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
               } catch (SAXException sae) {
                sae.printStackTrace();
               }            

          }               
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this a bit differently:

1. List all files in directory
2. Loop through items in the list of files
3. Extract old id and increment it
4. Process new id

Example:

```
//you could probably make this nicer

String fileNamePattern = "CRM_CI_\\d{8}_\\d{6}_\\d{8}\\.zip";
String oldProvIdPattern = "CRM_CI_\\d{8}_\\d{6}_(\\d{8})\\.zip";

String pathToZips = "/Users/John.Smith/Desktop/Test_script/"
String destinationPath = "/Users/John.Smith/Desktop/Test_script/test";

File dir = new File(".");
FileFilter fileFilter = new RegexFileFilter(fileNamePattern);
File[] files = pathToZips.listFiles(fileFilter);
for (File file : files) {
    //Handle each zip here
    String zipPath = file.getAbsolutePath();  


    try {
        unzipper.unzip(zipPath, destinationPath);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("ERROR:Unzip did not work");
    }

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(oldProvIdPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(file.getName());
    if (matcher.find()){
        String old_prov_id = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.println("Old provider ID :"+old_prov_id );

        // add +1 to provider ID
        int new_provider_ID = Integer.parseInt(old_prov_id);
        new_provider_ID++;
        System.out.println("New provider ID :"+new_provider_ID );

        // convert provider-id INT into String   

        String str_provider_id = Integer.toString(new_provider_ID);  
        System.out.println("New String provider ID :"+str_provider_id );  

        // concatenate two String into one
        StringBuilder bufferPDF = new StringBuilder()
                .append(new_provider_ID).append(".pdf");
            System.out.println(bufferPDF.toString()); 

            StringBuilder bufferXML = new StringBuilder()
                    .append(new_provider_ID).append(".xml");
                System.out.println(bufferXML.toString()); 

        // convert names of XML and PDF      

       Path sourcePDF = Paths.get("/Users/John.Smith/Desktop/Test_script/test/" + old_prov_id + ".pdf");
        try {
            Files.move(sourcePDF, sourcePDF.resolveSibling(bufferPDF.toString()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Path sourceXML = Paths.get("/Users/John.Smith/Desktop/Test_script/test/" + old_prov_id + ".xml");
        try {
            Files.move(sourceXML, sourceXML.resolveSibling(bufferXML.toString()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // change provider-id and filename in xml file    

        try {

        String filepath = "/Users/John.Smith/Desktop/Test_script/test/" + old_prov_id + ".xml";

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);

        // Get the root element provider-id 
        Node provider = doc.getElementsByTagName("provider-id").item(0);
        provider.setTextContent(str_provider_id);

        // Get the root element filename
        Node filename = doc.getElementsByTagName("filename").item(0);
        filename.setTextContent(str_provider_id);


        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        System.out.println("Done");

       } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
       } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
       } catch (SAXException sae) {
        sae.printStackTrace();
       }            

      }  
}
```

Comment: You could also replace all the instances of "/Users/John.Smith/Desktop/Test_script/test" with the destinationPath variable

Comment: Hi Vio, tnx for quick response. All looks good but i am getting the following error "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )" for fileNamePattern and oldProvIdPattern.

Comment: All backslashes '\' need to be escaped with another backslash "\\"

Answer (score 1):

If you got you correctly, you main problem is that you have a string like

```
CRM_CI_20161016_000001_50661561.zip
```

And you want to fetch 50661561

If so, you can simply use the[String.lastIndexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)) method.
Simply do a

```
String input = "CRM....
int indexOfLastUnderScore = input.lastIndexOf('_');
int indexOfZipExtension = input.lastIndexOf('.');
String substringWithNumer = input.substring(indexOfLastUnderScore+1, indexOfZipExtension);
```

Of course, you can also turn to regular expressions here, but I think pushing something like the above code into a small helper method is more maintainable in the long run.

( hint: I didn't run my code through the compiler; so beware of typos or subtle "off by one" errors; but it should be good enough to get you going )

Comment: Tnx for a quick answer. My first problem is the String that need to be concatenated from Path and zip file name. The second problem is to loop trought the zip file names (path+zip file name).